# PetaPoco one-to-one relationship

Tags: orm, relationship, petapoco

I'm trying to figure out how to do a simple one-to-one relationship with PetaPoco in Umbraco 7.

The ideal solution would be for my Peta object to contain a definition for another Peta model, which will be eager loaded when the object is instantiated. Etc. i have two Petas

Country and Sport.
The sport peta has a country_id column. When  i instantiate the sport object
i would like to be able to do a:

```
SportPeta.Country.Name;
```

Instad of having to either "Select the sport Peta with a join clause" or running multiple selects.

Is this merely possible?

Thanks in advance
Jonas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PetaPoco it's a microORM and doesn't do this automatically, you have to do it yourself using a property getter.

But, keep in mind that having this kind of lazy loading properties can fire lot's of DB calls without you even knowing.

My recommendation is having a ResultColumn for the really common join properties, like country name, and populate it using a SQL join